# Can I compare IF and FOR in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with this code, Can i Use a IF beetwen a FOR in python?

In this code I want know if the first letter is a consonant or a vowel, but the code do a error

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
word = word.lower()
vowel="aeiou"
if word[0] == for i in vowel:
        word = word+"way"
        print(word)
else:
        word = word[1:len(word)] +"ay"
        print(word)
```

**Input In [16]
if word[0] == for i in vowel:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Can I compare FOR with an IF? What is the correct sintax for that?

Comment: Since this gives you an error, and you know it gives you an error, the answer is "no, you can't". We don't know what you should do instead, though, because you didn't say what you think this invalid syntax should do. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop at all. Instead, you can use the `in` operator to check if a string contains a substring, like so:

```py
word = input("Enter a word: ")
word = word.lower()
vowel = "aeiou"

if word[0] in vowel:
  word = word + "way"
  print(word)
else:
  word = word[1:len(word)] + "ay"
  print(word)
```

For example, if you ran this code and entered "hello", the result would be "elloay". If you entered "aardvark", the result would be "aardvarkway".

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is move the `for` loop outside the `if` statement. It should look something like this:

```py
word = input("Enter a word: ")
word = word.lower()
vowel="aeiou"
for i in vowel:
    if word[0] == i:
            word = word+"way"
            print(word)
    else:
            word = word[1:len(word)] +"ay"
            print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

other way to do this maybe more simple or efficient

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
word = word+'way' if word.lower()[0] in ['a','e','i','o','u'] else word[1:len(word)]+'ay'
print(word)
```